# Tibble columns of class tibble instead of class data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, nested, purrr, tibble

What's the tidy way of having `tibble` columns of class `tibble` (instead of class `list` or `data.frame`)?

It's clearly possible to have columns of class `data.frame` in `tibble`s (see
example below), but none of the "tidy ways of data manipulation" (i.e.
`dplyr::mutate()` or `purrr::map*_df()`) seem to work for me when trying to cast the columns to `tibble` instead of `data.frame`

#### Current ouput of `jsonlite::fromJSON()`

```r
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ labels  :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#  $ levelOne:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ levelTwo:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#  $ schema  : chr  "0.0.1" "0.0.1"
```

#### Desired result

```r
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ labels  :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#  $ levelOne:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ levelTwo:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#  $ schema  : chr  "0.0.1" "0.0.1"
```

#### Why having `data.frame` columns can be very misleading

https://hendrikvanb.gitlab.io/2018/07/nested_data-json_to_tibble/

#### Related

- [Recursively ensuring tibbles instead of data frames when parsing/manipulating nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59717301/recursively-ensuring-tibbles-instead-of-data-frames-when-parsing-manipulating-ne)
- [Ensure that data frames become tibbles when reading MongoDB data with {mongolite}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59717624/ensure-that-data-frames-become-tibbles-when-reading-mongodb-data-with-mongolite?noredirect=1#comment105604985_59717624)

---

### Example

#### Example data

```r
library(magrittr)

json <- '[
  {
    "labels": ["label-a", "label-b"],
    "levelOne": {
      "levelTwo": {
        "levelThree": [
          {
            "x": "A",
            "y": 1,
            "z": true
          },
          {
            "x": "B",
            "y": 2,
            "z": false
          }
          ]
      }
    },
    "schema": "0.0.1"
  },
  {
    "labels": ["label-a", "label-b"],
    "levelOne": {
      "levelTwo": {
        "levelThree": [
          {
            "x": "A",
            "y": 10,
            "z": false
          },
          {
            "x": "B",
            "y": 20,
            "z": true
          }
          ]
      }
    },
    "schema": "0.0.1"
  }
]'
```

When visualizing this, you'll see that there's a subtle but important distinction between **objects** (which map to `data.frame`s) and **array** (which map to `list`s):

[image]

#### Parsing JSON and converting to `tibble`

```r
x <- json %>% 
  jsonlite::fromJSON() %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()

x %>% str()
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ labels  :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#  $ levelOne:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ levelTwo:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#  $ schema  : chr  "0.0.1" "0.0.1"
```

So it's clearly possible to have columns that are of class `data.frame`.

#### Casting `data.frame` to `tibble` columns: "the bad way"

But I'd like tibbles instead of data frames, so let's try the only thing I got
to work: explicit re-assigning the respective list levels, or data frame/tibble
columns, to be more precise:

```r
# Make a copy so we don't mess with the initial state of `x`
y <- x

y$levelOne <- y$levelOne %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()
y$levelOne$levelTwo <- y$levelOne$levelTwo %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()
y$levelOne$levelTwo$levelThree <- y$levelOne$levelTwo$levelThree %>% 
  purrr::map(tibble::as_tibble)

x %>% str()
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ labels  :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#  $ levelOne:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ levelTwo:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#  $ schema  : chr  "0.0.1" "0.0.1"
```

That works, but is not in line with "tidy data manipulation pipes".

#### Casting `data.frame` to `tibble` columns: "the better way" (trying and failing)

```r
# Yet another copy so we can compare:
z <- x

# Just to check that this works
z$levelOne %>% 
    tibble::as_tibble()
# # A tibble: 2 x 1
#   levelTwo$levelThree
#   <list>             
# 1 <df[,3] [2 × 3]>   
# 2 <df[,3] [2 × 3]>   

# Trying to get this to work with `dplzr::mutate()` fails:
z %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(levelOne = levelOne %>% 
    tibble::as_tibble()
  )
# Error: Column `levelOne` is of unsupported class data.frame

z %>% 
  dplyr::transmute(levelOne = levelOne %>% 
    tibble::as_tibble()
  )
# Error: Column `levelOne` is of unsupported class data.frame

# Same goes for `{purrr}`:
z %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(levelOne = levelOne %>% 
    purrr::map_df(tibble::as_tibble)
  )
# Error: Column `levelOne` is of unsupported class data.frame

z %>% 
  tibble::add_column(levelOne = z$levelOne %>% tibble::as_tibble())
# Error: Can't add duplicate columns with `add_column()`:
# * Column `levelOne` already exists in `.data`.

# Works, but not what I want:
z %>% 
  tibble::add_column(test = z$levelOne %>% tibble::as_tibble()) %>% 
  str()
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
#  [...]
#  $ test    :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ levelTwo:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
```

#### The only thing that worked (is not what we want)

Wrapping `tibble::as_tibble()` by `purrr::map()` **seems** to work, but the result is clearly not what we want as we duplicate everything below `levelOne` (compare to desired output above)

```r
# Works, but not what I want:
z_new <- z %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(levelOne = levelOne %>% 
    purrr::map(tibble::as_tibble)
  )

z_new %>% str()
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ labels  :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#  $ levelOne:List of 2
#   ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#   ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#  $ schema  : chr  "0.0.1" "0.0.1"
```

---

## EDIT (follow-up investigation)

Got it to work with Hendrik's help!

Still, IMO this topic raises some interesting follow-up questions regarding
whether or not one should - or even **could** - do it any other way if the primary
goal is to end up with tidy nested tibbles that play nicely with
`tidyr::unnset()` and `tidyr::nest()` (see comments in Hendrik's answer below).

As to the proposed approach in
https://hendrikvanb.gitlab.io/2018/07/nested_data-json_to_tibble/: I might be 
overlooking something obvious, but I think it only works for JSON docs with a
single document.

First, let's modify `df_to_tibble()` (see Hendrik's answer below) to only turn
"leaf" data frames into tibbles while turning "branch" data frames into lists:

```r
leaf_df_to_tibble <- function(x) {
  if (is.data.frame(x)) {
    if (!any(purrr::map_lgl(x, is.list))) { 
      # Only captures "leaf" DFs:
      tibble::as_tibble(x) 
    } else {
      as.list(x)
    }
  } else {
    x
  }
}
```

This would give us results that are in line with the proposed way in the blog post, but only for "single object" JSON docs as illustrated below

```r
df <- json %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()

# Only take the first object from the parsed JSON:
df_subset <- df[1, ]
```

Transforming `df_subset`:

```r
df_subset_tibble <- purrr::reduce(
  0:purrr::vec_depth(df_subset),
  function(x, depth) {
    purrr::modify_depth(x, depth, leaf_df_to_tibble, .ragged = TRUE)
  }, 
  .init = df_subset
) %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()

df_subset_tibble %>% str()
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ labels  :List of 1
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#  $ levelOne:List of 1
#   ..$ levelTwo:List of 1
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 1
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#  $ schema  : chr "0.0.1"
```

Transforming `df`:

```r
df_tibble <- purrr::reduce(
  0:purrr::vec_depth(df),
  function(x, depth) {
    purrr::modify_depth(x, depth, leaf_df_to_tibble, .ragged = TRUE)
  }, 
  .init = df
) %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble()

df_tibble %>% str()
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ labels  :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#  $ levelOne:List of 2
#   ..$ levelTwo:List of 1
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#   ..$ levelTwo:List of 1
#   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#   .. .. ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#  $ schema  : chr  "0.0.1" "0.0.1"
```

As we see, "listifying" nested JSON structures actually may results in copying
the "leafs". It just doesn't jump at you as long as `n = 1` (number of JSON
docs), but strikes you as soon as `n > 1`.

Comment: Wow. That’s a lot of code for what sounds like a simple solution to the title question. I’m pretty sure tibbles handle columns that are lists better than data frames do.

Comment: @42: I agree that lists would be the preferred "entry point" for nested structures. But what do you make of the parsed result of nested JSONs that do have nested documents (mapping to DFs/tibbles) as opposed to only arrays (which would map to lists). I'm trying to capture the structure that's given to me (as does `jsonlite::fromJSON()`, but it unfortunately maps to `data.frame` instead of  `tibble` columns)

Comment: @42: Also a very good blog post about why having `data.frame` columns can be very misleading: https://hendrikvanb.gitlab.io/2018/07/nested_data-json_to_tibble/

Comment: I've also updated the post to better visualize the different JSON components (documents vs. arrays). That's the main point why we can't use "lists only"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Background

The comments above raise some valid points. Still, I do believe there is a way to achieve what you're after (whether or not this is a particularly good idea is less clear) by leveraging three functions from the `purrr` package in combination:

1. `purrr::vec_depth` allows us to get the (nesting) depth of a given list,
2. `purrr::modify_depth` allows us to apply a function to an list at the specified  level of depth, and
3. `purrr::reduce` allows us to iteratively apply a function and have the result of each iteration be passed as the input to the subsequent iteration.

## General approach

In essence, we want to convert any `data.frame` found at any level in the list to a `tibble`. This can easily be achieved using several rounds of `purrr::modify_depth` where we simply alter the depth depending on the level of the list we wish to target.  Crucially, however, we want to do this in a way so that changes to level 1, for example, are retained when we move on to targeting level 2; changes to level 1 and 2 are retained when we move on to level 3; and so on.  This is where `purrr::reduce` comes in: each time we apply `purrr::modify_depth` to convert a data.frame to a tibble, we'll ensure that the resultant output gets passed as the input to the next iteration.  This is illustrated in the MWE below

## MWE

Start with the basic setup of data structures and libraries

```
#> Load libraries ----
library(tidyverse)

json <- '[
  {
    "labels": ["label-a", "label-b"],
    "levelOne": {
      "levelTwo": {
        "levelThree": [
          {
            "x": "A",
            "y": 1,
            "z": true
          },
          {
            "x": "B",
            "y": 2,
            "z": false
          }
          ]
      }
    },
    "schema": "0.0.1"
  },
  {
    "labels": ["label-a", "label-b"],
    "levelOne": {
      "levelTwo": {
        "levelThree": [
          {
            "x": "A",
            "y": 10,
            "z": false
          },
          {
            "x": "B",
            "y": 20,
            "z": true
          }
          ]
      }
    },
    "schema": "0.0.1"
  }
]'  

# convert json to a nested data.frame
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json)
```

Now we'll create a simple helper function that can conditionally convert `data.frame` to `tibble`

```
# define a simple function to convert data.frame to tibble
df_to_tibble <- function(x) {
  if (is.data.frame(x)) as_tibble(x) else x
}
```

Now for the crucial routine: Taking `df` as the initial starting point (`.init = df`), apply the `df_to_tibble` function at each level of `df` (`0:purrr::vec_depth(df)`) using `purrr::modify_depth`. Use `purrr::reduce` to ensure that the results from each individual iteration gets passed as the input to the subsequent iteration.

```
# create df_tibble by reducing the result of applying df_to_tibble to each level
# of df via purrr's modify_depth function %>% lastly, ensure that the top level
# data.frame is also converted to a tibble
df_tibble <- purrr::reduce(
  0:purrr::vec_depth(df),
  function(x, depth) {
    purrr::modify_depth(x, depth, df_to_tibble, .ragged = TRUE)
  }, 
  .init = df
) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

```
# show the structure of df_tibble
str(df_tibble)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ labels  :List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#>   ..$ : chr  "label-a" "label-b"
#>  $ levelOne:Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ levelTwo:Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   .. ..$ levelThree:List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#>   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  1 2
#>   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  TRUE FALSE
#>   .. .. ..$ :Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   .. .. .. ..$ x: chr  "A" "B"
#>   .. .. .. ..$ y: int  10 20
#>   .. .. .. ..$ z: logi  FALSE TRUE
#>  $ schema  : chr  "0.0.1" "0.0.1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is **exactly** what I was looking for, down to to the actual implementation via `{purrr}`!

Comment: Curious to know, though: why do you think swapping `data.frame` for `tibble` is a bad idea when being confronted with nested JSON objects? Would `data.frame` be the better choice (as implemented by `jsonlite::fromJSON()`) and why so? Or are you advocating that nested JSON objects should rather be mapped to columns with `list(data.frame(...))` or `list(tibble())` instead of `data.frame(data.frame(...))` or `tibble(tibble(...))` in general? If the latter, then wouldn't that completely change the structure which in turn would result in a different JSON when parsing back out?

Comment: I'm not sure what the advantages are to simply swapping `data.frame` out for `tibble`, but as I try to show in this blog post (https://hendrikvanb.gitlab.io/2018/07/nested_data-json_to_tibble/), there are good reasons to want to ensure that `data.frame` objects included in other `data.frame` objects are included as `list` columns - TL;DR: it helps to ensure that the nested `data.frame` can be unnested into a tidy, rectangular/flat `data.frame` for the purposes of wrangling/analysis.  I'm all for nested `tibbles`, but only if they are actually easy to navigate (i.e. can be unnested  if needed).

Comment: Okay, got it. I guess as a general approach, I also favor "staying tidy" by having `list(data.frame(...))` columns. But when you need to preserve the overall structure of a MongoDB/JSON doc, then I at least don't see a direct way of ensuring tidy structures. Of course one could write some data mappers for I/O to decouple the data structure for data analysis from the actual one in the DB. Would you tackle use cases as mine that way?

Comment: One thing I noticed when trying out the "JSON > list > tibble" approach in your blog post: I don't see how it's applicable when you have more than one top-level JSON object that you want to bring into a tidy format of a nested tibble. As soon as you call `as.list()` on a branch level data frame, don't you inevitably duplicate all the leafs? See the edit in my answer for details